# My XML file doesn't seem to be pushing the values to my code. Causing my tests to be skipped

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng.xml

I am setting up test cases for practice and trying to feed the parameters from an XML file for the website url, and the desired browser if available. The Switch logic, and webdriver commands look solid, but maybe i missed something that makes it skip them entirely. Should output that login was successful on both occasions.

In the past I've simply fed the data in as variables, this is my first try with xml handling the data injection.

public class NewTest {

WebDriver driver;

@Test(dataProvider="getData") 
public void login(String username,String password) 
      {
           //Code to Login to the application

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'myNavbar\']/ul/li[4]/a")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("usernameLogin")).sendKeys(username);
driver.findElement(By.id("passwordLogin")).sendKeys(password);
driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();

   try
            {
```

`````````````````````````````````````````````
                 //verifying the presence of webelement
````````````````````````````````````````````
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.id("topMenu2")));
    System.out.println("login success");
                }
    catch(Exception e)
                {
    System.out.println("Login failure");

                }
    driver.findElement(By.id("topMenu2")).click();

          }


  @DataProvider
  public Object[][]getData() {
      Object[][]data=new Object[2][2];
      data[0][0]="pgGru";
      data[0][1]="freezeray";
      data[1][0]="pgAlmacho";
      data[1][1]="freezeray";
      return data;  
  }


  @BeforeSuite  
  @Parameters({ "browsername", "url" })
  public void setup(@Optional("Firefox")String browsername,String url) {    
    switch (browsername) {
    case "IE":
    WebDriver driver1;
    driver1 = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    System.setProperty("webdriver.IEDriverServer.driver", "D:\\Jarrrs\\Drivers\\IEDriverServer_win32");
    driver1.get(url);
    break;
    case "Firefox":
    WebDriver driver2;
    driver2 = new FirefoxDriver();
    System.setProperty("webdriver.geckodriver.driver","D:\\Jarrrs\\Drivers\\gecfkoDriver_win32");
    driver2.get(url);
    break;
    case "chrome":
    WebDriver driver3;
    driver3 = new ChromeDriver();
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver, ","D:\\Jarrrs\\Drivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver3.get(url);
    break;  
    }   
  }


  @AfterSuite
  public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();    
  }
}

Right now the output is it is skipping the test cases for login and password
Expecting two passed or failed tests. Either one would be nice.
`````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Why don't you create `WebDriver driver` before the switch and use it in all the cases? I don't see the logic to get the values from xml and entering.

Comment: It was created outside of the @BeforeSuite, and in the main class body.

Answer (score 0):

Newbie here. What do you mean by test is skipping? Are the actions within login() not being executed? I would put sys.out statements withing login() to check if the code is getting executed. How about adding a pause after page load? How about adding hardcoded value to username and password field to check if it is working fine?
Some times certain fields cannot be set by using Selenium's sendkeys. Need to use JavascriptExecutor to set the field values